# Fix IP of non-default module in App engine development server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am testing a multi module App Engine project. Every time I run the application using `dev_appserver.sh` I ca see different ports getting assigned to a module which is not default.

Is there a way I can fix the port numbers for the non-default modules in dev server.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799435/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113299/?

Comment: @konqi thanks for the links